# How to get this format moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ssZ') javascript in php?

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, momentjs

I wish to achieve this same date format from javascript in php:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ssZ');
```

output: `2016-12-24T13:46:43-05:00`

I'm trying to get the same result, but I've only gotten the following:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s-ssZ');
```

output: `2022-09-22T14:42:28-28280`

I don't know if the procedure is correct, but I want to get the same javascript date format but in PHP, what changes should I add to my code?

Comment: The procedure is correct, you just need different formatting tokens. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php lists what you can use. `s` is for seconds, it has nothing to do with the timezone offset.

Comment: @ADyson So it would be like this: `echo $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s-s-s');` But the output is weird: `2022-09-22T14:56:15-15-15` This is repeated a lot: `15-15-15`

Comment: No, not like that. Why do you keep repeating the number of seconds? Read the documentation, and also my answer below.

Comment: @ADyson The closest thing is this format: `c  ISO 8601 date` since the output is: `2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00` the only problem is the + sign, it must be - any idea friend?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea. Again, read the documentation, and my answer below, both of which explain it clearly.

Comment: `-ssZ` - what do you expect from that part?

Comment: `the + sign, it must be -`...why must it? It must only be `-` if the timezone offset is negative. In the case that your timezone has the same time as GMT, then you'll see +00:00 naturally, because the time is 0 hours and minutes ahead of GMT. This is normal, standard, and expected. I wonder if the real problem here is that you don't actually understand what the meaning of the `-05:00` in your example is. That might explain why you hard-coded a `-` into your own attempt.

Comment: @ADyson It is the date format that the api accepts for sending an xml file on the subject of electronic invoicing

Comment: Sure. And it will accept a `+` too I expect, since that's also a valid character in a timezone offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure is correct, you just need different formatting tokens. The [documentation for DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) lists what you can use.

What you can use in this case is `P` - the documentation says:

> Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes   Example: +02:00

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/PjI5m

N.B. `s` is for seconds, it has nothing to do with the timezone offset, so I'm not really sure why you used that, especially when you'd already used it to display seconds a bit earlier in the same formatting string (thus making it clear that is has a different purpose). Keep in mind that PHP's date formatting tokens are not the same as the ones used by momentJS.

Comment: How can we replace the + with -? from this: `2022-09-22T16:56:22+02:00` to this friend: `2022-09-22T16:56:22-02:00`

Comment: You don't want to do that, because the version with the `-` is representing time 4 hours earlier than the one with the `+`. Again, I think the root of the problem here is that you don't actually understand the data you're working with.

Comment: It depends on the timezone. You don't need to replace it. When using Javascript, it is using your computers local timezone, but on server (if the server is not your computer), you might have a different timezone.

Comment: @ADyson I hope there is no problem, I will try with this output, otherwise I will comment again, it is not that I do not understand, I just wanted to have the same javascript format so as not to have problems with the signing of the xml file. Thank you :)

Comment: `I just wanted to have the same javascript format`...and now you do. `it is not that I do not understand`...are you sure? No offence but I think if you understood that the data you're looking at is a a timezone offset, and you understand how one of those works, then you wouldn't ask to swap the `+` and `-`, because you would know their significance. :-)

Comment: Also, your Javascript could easily produce the same `+` at times. Look at the momentJS documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ For the `Z` token it gives examples of what it produces, such as `-07:00 -06:00 ... +06:00 +07:00`. So you can see, it's just the same.